# Modify ruby routes.rb to allow two urls to be supported from one VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use some open source ruby software, with limited familarity with ruby.  The original code supported two URLs, mainSite and api.mainsite

I want to change this so these two locations point to the same localhost, and am having difficulty.  Here is a snippet of the code that I think is relelvant.

```
lambda_api_host = lambda { |request| request.host == URI.parse(Api::Application.config.api_url).host }
lambda_www_host = lambda { |request| request.host == URI.parse(Api::Application.config.www_url)

#www.mainSite.com
scope constraints: lambda_www_host do

  ...

end

  # api.mainSite.com
scope constraints: lambda_api_host do

  ....

end
```

I've read through the routes.rb and tried a few changes but so far none have worked.  I can't get the "api" one to point to localhost without an internal error.

Note, the code has redirects that use Api::Application.config.api_url to build the url to redirect to

Comment: "without an internal error." What error?

Comment: I get a 500 internal error with most of the changes I tried.  I think it's because it can't find the url.  I tried pointint one to localhost and the other to localhost/api but I believe it is then looking for api/controller instead of just controller.  I'm not certain because I'm also learning how to debug with rubymine and so far If I put one break point it breaks in 100 different places, making it hard to pinpoint the cause of the 500 errors...

Comment: Please copy the entire log action and error message from `log/development.log` and include it in your question.  Post everything from the `Started` line to the `Completed` line for the action that's failing, including the full error with complete backtrace.